# For slower connection user i want replace video tag with an image tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have placed an video in my webpage but that video is large in size, so that it will load slowly for low internet speed connection user.

For high internet speed users, video will be played as it is and for low internet speed users, an image will be displayed instead of that video(video will not played for low internet speed user)

guys can u please help me out of this

guys it will be possible r not....!

Comment: replace your video tag with img tag.Else till your video gets loaded u can show user a posterimage.

Comment: hi @AkshayJ can u please explain in detail

Answer (score 2):

You can use poster attribute in your video tag in the meanwhile the video is getting downloaded.

```
<video controls poster="/images/w3html5.gif">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Else if you want to replace video with image just change your video tag to img tag :)